# Open emacs in a terminal when editing crontab

Tags: bash, cron, emacs

I have setup `emacs` as my default editor in `/etc/profile`. When I want to use `emacs` in a terminal. I open it with the `-nw` option. How can I have the same behavior when doing a `crontab -e` preventing it to open in a window?

Comment: "I have setup emacs as my default editor in /etc/profile" how?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to use

```
    export EDITOR="emacs -nw"
```

with the quotes, and it should work as expected.

Answer (score 7):

If you think starting `emacs` every time is slow, you can also use:

```
export EDITOR="emacsclient -t"
```

However, you will have to start the emacs server once using:

```
emacs --daemon
```

Comment: With `EDITOR="emacsclient --alternate-editor= -t"`, emacsclient will start Emacs in daemon mode if necessary.